# Real error text with BULK_EXCEPTIONS in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to know real reason, real ora code (in this case unique key violation) when using

```
    FORALL var_i_idx IN 1..table_of_t.count SAVE EXCEPTIONS
    INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES (                          
        table_of_t(var_i_idx).var_id);
        RETURN retVal;
        EXCEPTION
           WHEN OTHERS
           THEN
              IF SQLCODE = -24381
              THEN
                 FOR var_i_idx IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
                 LOOP
                 v_action := 'Insert table_of_t';
                 v_error_text := 'Unexcpected exception SQLCODE: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (var_i_idx).ERROR_INDEX || ' -- ERROR:' || sqlerrm(SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (var_i_idx).ERROR_CODE);
dbms_output.put_line('Unexcpected exception SQLCODE: '||SQLCODE||' -- ERROR: '||SQLERRM);
```

DBMS will print following :Unexcpected exception SQLCODE: -24381 -- ERROR: ORA-24381: error(s) in array DML

But is it possible to know real reason ?

Comment: I would expect SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_CODE to be what you are looking for but your code snippet appears to be incomplete so I can't say for certain.  I see IF but no END If and LOOP but no END LOOP.  And the assignment to v_error_test has highlighting that would indicate a string which might indicate a misplaced single quote. Please post a minimal reproducible sample with DDL and sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the actual error message, although only the base message. The issue you have is your dbms_output message is for the bulk error not the individual item errors. You get the item error from the ERROR_CODE in the SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS collections. Even more you access the actual data causing the exception through ERROR_INDEX. This indexes the entry in the collection named in the forall statement. Skeleton access for error message and bulk collection (where blk_array is the name of the collection used in the forall).  See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=158cd74bc5f935b91efae13626f047c5);

```
for err_idx in 1 .. sql%bulk_exceptions
loop     
    msg := sqlerrm(-sql%bulk_exceptions(err_idx).error_code);   
    val := blk_array(sql%bulk_exceptions(err_idx).error_index);
end loop;
```

In the fiddle ignore the code setting up the FORALL, that was available for another task entirely. Just concentrate on the Exception section except for the lines:

```
declare
    errors_during_forall exception;                       -- create name for errors during bulk, forall, processing
    pragma exception_init (errors_during_forall, -24381); -- and tie that name to the actual Oracle error number
```

This allows you to define a name to the exception and then reference that name is the EXCEPTION section.

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue. However I am getting ORA-00001: unique constraint (.) violated. Is it possible to see which constraint ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. That is what a I meant by base message only. The trouble is Oracle only stores the error number not the detail message. However you should be able to determine this as you can get the actual values involved in the error. You can then do a select against your different unique indexed from those values.

Comment: Thanks! How do you get the actual values involved in the error ?

Comment: Look at the fiddle referenced. In the exception settion the  line  "v_error_msg  := 'Source Item: ' || toj(sql%bulk_exceptions(err_idx).error_index);" Is retrieving the actual values, yours will obviously differ based on the definition of the collection used in the forall. The Error_index in the sql%bulk_exceptions is the iteration into that collection. For a dense collection indexed by an integer type (as in this case) the iteration and index are the same.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer. Do not leave a satisfactory answered question an unanswered. An answered question may help others later that have a similar question.